# Resign from company because of almost 1 year development of meaningless project?

Tags: resignation

I've been in a new company for almost a year and a half. The company is small (15 people), most of them including me are software/web developers (10 people).

On February we started to work on some new project which I immediately knew would fail. The project idea is too complex and therefore no customer would want to purchase it. The project is web application for transport management. The web application is missing good user experience and also there are a lot of open questions/issued that need to be resolved.

Basically after 10 months we developed this project for nothing. I personally learned a lot of new things (deepen my knowledge of .NET, multilayer development) but as time passed by I got more and more depressed about the project. It turned out in October that "management" finally killed the project, but now we are still developing some modules for potentially one customer (management decided to enable development again).

I've come to the point where I just want to quit the company. If you see that the project is going nowhere there is no point in developing it further (the customer confirmed that its too complex). Am I going too far by quitting the company? The other team members feel the same, but they just don't care. I think employees stay for three reasons:

- the salary is good
- it's a time in their lives where they can't afford to switch jobs
- they just don't care

But again how can you develop something if you don't care?

Comment: Job satisfaction is very important to a lot of people. I know it's important to me. And obviously working on a doomed project won't give you much satisfaction. So if this is bothering you, then by all means leave. But find a new job first!

Comment: Welcome to product development. Not every project goes to completion,, makes it to the market, success in the market, or survives for long after that. Care about what you're doing, but don't bet you self esteem on soneone else's decisions -- management or customers.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I going to far for quitting the company?

That depends. Do you have another job lined up? It is almost never a good idea to quit without another job lined up. If so, put in your notice. No need to over think this. If not, start looking for a new job. Once you have a signed contract, put in your notice.

When I read your post, I get the feeling that you want to be working on something you are excited about. Something you care about. That is awesome. Some people could care less. A job is a job to them. It is what enables them to do the real things they like (boating, fishing, skiing, video games, etc.) For you, it sounds like you want more out of your job/career. Awesome, now go find that job!

Comment: Good point about first finding your next job then quit. Well I suppose I could apply for new job. It's just that you can't be focused on something when you see it's gonna die. Further more how can you sell something you don't believe into? It's important to develop things that matter.

Comment: @banduser, you can't let things like this affect your motivation to do your job. Of course you can be focused on it. Won;t be the last time in your career that things are not so great. As long as they are paying you, you need to accomplish what they are paying for whether you agree with it or are excited about it or not. Use your feelings about it to decide if you want to stay or go or propose a new project, yes. Use it to decide if you if you are in the mood to work on it today, no.